# How to create game map for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to create a game map for stages and levels within a game similar to the way the game Candy Crush or Two Dots have done for iOS devices. However, I want to ask the best and easiest way to achieve something like this in Swift...

[image: Candy Crush]
[image: Two Dots]

Thanks

Comment: To create game like this, swift/objective c is not what you should looking at.... You should either go for Unity5 2D or cocos2dx game engine. I would suggest you to choose Unity5 environment when it comes to game development.

Comment: @Arun I disagree, depends on his goals. If he wants to create iOS only game or this is just learning excerise, then going with swift and some gamedev libraries is arguably better way. If OP plans to create game for multiple platforms then you are of course right

Comment: Lope, if he is planning to create something like candycrash...then its highly impossible in swift alone. It would take him years to complete that in swift.. I have been game developer for quite a while and I was suggesting him the best technology available to create games something like that. Yes, if its just for learning swift, then fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way, just draw the image with path and background, mark the positions of levels and then place level icon on each position. If you don't need to move the player's avatar along the line, this will do.

However, if you want to show player's avatar moving from one level to another along the path, you will need to define those path using curves (bezier, cubic) and then calculate position of the player based on curve's formula and his progress between two levels